# Can a GCP f1 app engine instance run a Jhipster monolitic app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jhipster

I would like to know if anyone has tried to run a Jhipster webapp (basic: 4 entities) on a f1 Google Cloud app engine and if it has worked for them.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, \`App engine\` supports Jhipster monolitic app. For more information check this document: [https://www.jhipster.tech/gcp/\#deploy-to-google-app-engine](https://www.jhipster.tech/gcp/#deploy-to-google-app-engine)

Comment: F1 is a small instance. According to your resource requirement it could work or not.